# Creating a React Table with functional Components in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs, express

I'm new to this coding world and trying to learn Javascript and its frameworks. I'm trying to create a React table with functional components. I am able to create the table fine but the data is not rendering, tried using the fetch hook method. Can anyone help me out with something else ? Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import '../components/mystyle.css'

const FunctionalComponent = () => {

    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState({});
    const [isError, setErrors] = useState(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {

        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/employees");
            res
              .json()
              .then(res => setEmployees({employeeDetails: res}))
              .catch(err => setErrors(err));
          }
      
          fetchData();
        }, []);

    
        useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const resctc = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/employee/ctc");
            resctc
              .json()
              .then(resctc => setEmployees({totalCtc: resctc}))
              .catch(err => setErrors(err));
          }
      
          fetchData();
          
        }, []);
        
     const columns = [
        {
            Header: "EmployeeID",
            accessor: "EmployeeId",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center',
               
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "name",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Project",
            accessor: "Project",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Experience",
            accessor: "experience",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Salary",
            accessor: "salary",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "DateofJoining",
            accessor: "DOJ",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Blood Group",
            accessor: "Blood group",
            style: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        {
            Header: "Actions",
            Cell: props => {
                return (
                    <button style={
                        {
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            color: "red",
                            textAlign: 'center' 
                        }
                    }
                    >
                        View
                    </button>
                )
            },
            width: 100,
            maxWidth: 100,
            minWidth: 100,
           
        }
    ]
    return (
        
        <div>
            <div style={{  display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                maxWidth: '100',
                maxHeight: '100',
                padding: '20px',
                backgroundColor: '#fefefe'
            }}>

                <img src={Logo} alt={Logo} maxWidth='30px' />

            </div>


            <div class="container-fluid" >

                <div style={
                    {
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                        margin: '10px'
                    }
                }>

                    <div style={
                        {
                            maxWidth: '100',
                            fontSize: '2vw',
                            color: 'red'
                        }
                    }>Employee List</div>

                    <div style={
                        {
                            background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #f0f0f0 50%, blue 50%)',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            maxWidth: '100',
                            border: '1px solid blue',
                            borderRadius: '35px',
                            padding: '10px',

                        }
                    }>

                        <span style={
                            {
                                color: 'blue',
                                fontSize: '16px',
                                padding: '5px 24px',
                                borderRadius: '35px'
                            }

                        }
                        >Total CTC</span>


                        <span style={
                            { color: 'white', fontSize: '16px', padding: '5px 24px', borderRadius: '35px' }
                        }
                        >{employees.totalCtc}/-</span>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <ReactTable columns={columns} data={employees.employeeDetails} defaultPageSize={10}></ReactTable>
            </div>
            <div>
      <span>{JSON.stringify(employees)}</span>
      <hr />
    <span>Is Error: {JSON.stringify(isError)}</span>
    </div>

        </div>


    )
}

export default FunctionalComponent;
```

Comment: Employees should be array not object

Comment: Why do you have 2 useEffect with an empyt dependency?

Comment: There's good documentation to work through some examples: https://react-table.js.org/examples/simple